# Hiding all but the selected rows of data

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am unable to send any pictures,

The data contains 98 column headings, with the first column being unique identifiers, and 1000 rows of items.  I receive commentary on specific items throughout the day.  Updating those items is difficult because they are hard to locate.  I would like to be able to enter, in a specified input cell, a comma delimited list of the target items (on the order of 50 items), and have all of the data rows become hidden except for the rows of the specified items.

A VBA solution is acceptable.  I am currently trying to do this using filters but the quantity of items makes this unwieldy and I am looking for a better solution.

```
        col1      col2  .....col98
        UniqueID  header.....header

row1    ItemA1    Data2  ....Data98

row2    ItemA2    Data2  ....Data98

row3    ItemA3    Data2......Data98

row4    ItemA4    Data2......Data98
```

Input cell: A2,A3  hides all rows except the rows with A2,A3

```
        col1      col2  .....col98
        UniqueID  header.....header

row2    ItemA2    Data2  ....Data98

row3    ItemA3    Data2......Data98
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, its hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: so we have Named range cell  you enter unique reference or references followed by commar A1,A4

Comment: unique ref col 1      col heading 2  ...........colum heading99

Comment: So tell me if I understand.  The first column is a list of unique reference names and the row contains data associated with the reference.  You want to have a cell where you enter a comma delimited list of reference names and based on that list, hide all of the rows except for the ones whose reference names are in the list?  Can you clarify why filters can't be used?  Is it a requirement that the action happen in place or is it permissible for the output to be in another place (on that sheet or another sheet)?  Is use of VBA a requirement?

Comment: I am currently using filters, but the issue it is time consuming as I  have to select the appropriate unique references out of the 1000 references and than make the updates and save, this would be far easier, you could use various approaches, I feel this would be the most easiest way.

Comment: It looks like your comments to me don't get sent to the "inbox" unless you include @fixer1234.  I wasn't aware that you had replied until I just stumbled back across the question.  I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As Scott points out in his comment, the answer below does not provide the ability to navigate to and edit the source data, it only displays it.  His answer provides a solution to the question.  I'll leave the answer in place as general information in case someone needs a method to just display the selected data, and because Scott's answer references it.

There is a relatively simple way to do what you want by creating the output you want in another location rather than trying to hide rows (I believe that would require VBA).  There are two parts to the problem you described: entering your selections in a comma delimited list and using that, and displaying the selected rows.  You can simplify it by listing your selections individually in a column, so I'll cover the output first.

The output you want can be done using the VLOOKUP function.  You can create one generic formula and replicate it as needed.  In this step, I'll assume your selections are listed individually in a column.  If you enter them that way, all you need is this step.  If you want to use the comma delimited list, step two will decode that to create the individual selections in the column.

So let's assume your reference names are in column A, the associated data is in the 97 adjacent columns, and all of the data are in rows 2 through 1001.  I'll describe doing your output in another location on the same sheet.  If you want to do this on a separate sheet, just include the sheet reference as part of any cell reference that points to your data.

Let's assume that your output starts in column DA, row 2, and includes the next 97 columns.  The selections are entered in DA2 through DA50, or however many you need.  The entry in DB2 would be:

```
    =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($DA2,$A$2:$CW$1001,COL(DB2)-COL($DA2)+1,FALSE),"")
```

Quick explanation: The IFERROR at the beginning and double quotes at the end force blank output if the lookup produces an error.  This will happen if there is no entry in DA.  So if you start with no entries, the output will be blank.  If there are 10 entries, all the rows after that will be blank.

VLOOKUP looks for the selection entered in DA2, works with all of the data (I show it as A2:CW1001), compares DA2 to the entries in column A (the "false" specifies an exact match), and returns the contents in the associated column of data for the matching row.  Since the output columns are in the same relative positions as the data, the COL functions calculate the equivalent column in the data.  Copy this formula across all of the output columns and for as many rows as you need.

As the selections are entered in column DA, the data for each selection will appear.  If you want to enter the selections as a comma delimited list, keep in mind that there is a character limit for a cell.  If you are talking about 50 selections and the unique references are long, it could exceed the character limit.  That said, here is a way to decode it.  I will describe a method that isn't elegant, but it keeps it simple and easy to debug.

Let's assume you enter your list in DA1.  We will use the three columns to the left of DA to decode the list, so that would be CX, CY, and CZ.  In CX, we locate the commas.  The formula in CX2 is:

```
    =FIND(",",DA1)
```

After the first comma, we need to tell the FIND function where to start looking for the next one, so CX3 is:

```
    =FIND(",",$DA$1,CX2+1)
```

This formula can be copied down for as many rows as you need.  In each row, it will start looking in the character position after the last comma.  Next, we'll skip to column CZ and calculate the length of each selection.  In CZ2, the formula is:

```
    =IF(ISERROR(CX2),LEN($DA$1),CX2-1)
```

If no comma was found (an error was returned), there was either zero or one entries in the list, in which case the length is whatever is in the list.  Otherwise, it is one character fewer than the position of the comma.  For CZ3, the formula is:

```
    =IF(ISERROR(CX2),NA(),IF(ISERROR(CX3),LEN($DA$1)-CX2,CX3-CX2-1))
```

If no comma was found in the previous search, it means there is no selection to decode for this row and it returns an error code.  If no comma was found for the current row, it means that there is one more entry and its length is everything after the last comma.  If another comma was found, the length is the characters between the last two commas.  This formula can be copied down for as many rows as you need.

In column CY, we calculate the starting position of each entry in the list.  CY2 doesn't need a value because it is always the beginning.  The formula in CY3 is:

```
    =CZ2+2
```

That's the character after the length of the first item plus the comma.  The formula in CY4 is:

```
    =CY3+CZ3+1
```

That's the starting position of the previous item plus the length of the previous item plus the comma.  Copy that down for as many rows as you need.  Now you have identified where to find the entry in the list for each row.  The next step is to populate the selections.  The formula for DA2 is:

```
    =IF(ISBLANK(DA1),"",LEFT(DA1,CZ2))
```

If the list is empty, this returns a blank.  Otherwise it takes the leftmost characters for the length previously calculated.  The formula for DA3 is:

```
    =IF(OR(ISBLANK($DA$1),ISNA(CZ3)),"",MID($DA$1,CY3,CZ3))
```

If either the list is empty or the length calculation returned #NA, the result is blank.  Otherwise, it uses the calculated start position and length to return those characters from the list.  This formula can be copied down for as many rows as you need.  Now the output works the same as in the first part, only the selection entries are populated from the comma delimited list.

Comment: (1) I think you’re missing the point of the question. The OP doesn’t want merely to ***display*** the rows corresponding to the specified items – he wants to ***navigate*** to them, so he can update them. (2) Not all versions of Excel have a native `COL` function; I believe that `COLUMN` is the more portable name. (3) I figure the 98th column to be column `CT`, not `CW`.

Comment: 1. I do believe you're right.  I like what you did in your answer.  3. You're probably right but whose counting?

Comment: I love everyone's answers, let me explain why I want a vba solution  I have been doing vlooks and if statements its just become so time consuming,to move information and play around with a spreadsheets, end of the day, the spreadsheet items have to be sent to appropriate teams for next steps, you can be doing ten, or thirteen updates within hours, I can not keep playing around with vlookup etc or advance filters as the other items have to be on the next sheet. I like fixers solution, it close to what  I want but the issue is I am looking for a vba solution, the ideas you have r good

Comment: the stuff you have come out with can be applied to so many excel problems

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish different with VBA.  With @Scott's solution, there is some minimal one-time setup.  After that, it does exactly what you described in the question.  What is it that you want different in the result or the procedure that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you fixer and scott for your time and effort, its been a learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

fixer1234’s answer is a good start. 
I’ll assume that you have used the techniques in that answer to take the identifiers
that you are interested in and break them out into separate rows in column `DA`.  
And let’s assume that your identifiers are the states of the USA:

[image: worksheet with all states in column A, selected ones in col DA]

Enter some arbitrary heading in row 1 of some other unused column; e.g., `CZ`. 
Enter

```
=(COUNTIF(DA$2:DA$51,A2)>0)
```

into `CZ2` and drag down to cover all the rows where you have data (i.e., through row 1001). 
Note that my use of `DA$51` assumes that you have up to 50 targets that you’re searching for
(as you said). 
This will evaluate to `TRUE` on every row where the value in column `A` appears
(at least once) in column `DA`. 
Now filter column `CZ` and display only the rows where it is `TRUE`:

[image: filtered, showing only the states listed in column DA]

Comment: Scot how can I make this more dynamic? @scott

Comment: @user3287522: Please be more specific.

Comment: Lets suppose I select a validation linked to a list, I am keen for it to go to that heading in your case you have state, why if there was another heading population, month that it rained most, and than search my targets etc, I think this would require a offset on this formula =(COUNTIF(DA$2:DA$51,A2)>0)

Comment: of course my targets would have to be population figures, if I selected population etc..

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: Scott, your formula has saved me a lot of time, but I want to be able to filter by different columns headings, the example I used was unique reference as a heading and than my targets were unique references, although what you gave was generic, I want a list to be linked to A2

Comment: i have 98 column headings, so i want to be able filter different targets to those headings

Comment: I will give you example i was looking for a unique reference number was unable to locate it so i had to adjust the formula and search in the finished date column heading, search my target in that column and filter that item only, i.e the date i was searching for to get a unquie reference number

Comment: Scott, I  have come to this formula to replace your A value in A2 value its not working, =SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(A1,C1:G1,0),4),1,"") eg  =(COUNTIF(DA$2:DA$51,(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(A1,$C$1:$G$1,0),4),1,"")2)>0)