# How to parse delimited values in a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a cell containing **5;9;11;13;15;17**. There could be upto 15 different numbers in the cell. These numbers represent attributes.

For example **5** = Padlockable, **9** = Keylock etc. There are around 50 different types of attribute.

I am trying to create a Formula that will list (in the cell adjacent it) the actual values. Therefore the cell would display as follows: **Padlockable,Keylock,** etc.

Comment: Take a look at VLOOKUP: https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=1237

Comment: Many thanks for the tip! I have occasionally used VLOOKUP before, however I am struggling with all of the numbers being in the same cell. For example cell AI25 contains 5;9;11;13;15;1. Would this work with one cell containing all of these numbers?

Comment: If all of this numbers are in the same cell so probably not :( In this case it may be better to write a macro in VBA

Comment: You describe several steps: decode the string of numbers, lookup the translations, and build a new string from the translations.  Since there is a max of 15 values, you could build a "template" string of 15 placeholders and do some fancy cross reference lookups to populate it with text values or blanks.  Or, you could break down the source cell and then build the names cell word by word from the result.  You have the VLOOKUP part, just need to decode.  See the approach in the answer to this post: http://superuser.com/questions/822785/hiding-all-but-the-selected-rows-of-data/823367#823367

Comment: Many thanks to all, this is a bit of a struggle for my level of knowledge. In essence I am trying to create a VLOOKUP for every number between the ";" within the single cell. Therefore VLOOKUP, First Character, VLOOKUP, second character etc. Presently I have a named range of TEST and it looks like this: =VLOOKUP(F1,Test,2,FALSE). Obviously this does not  split up the string.

Comment: This problem has a two step solution - if you like. First split the string into individual columns and then use vlookup. Is that ok with you?

Comment: This would be a method I could probably understand :-) Thank you. Is there an easy to explain way of doing this?

Comment: See if the answer below is simple to understand. Comment my answer and I'll try to make it better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: Under the "Data" tab of excel - under Data tools group look for "Text to columns" icon.

Step-2: Select the text string you have to convert to columns

Step-3: click on Text to columns - in the dialog that opens select - Delimited option - Click "Next"

Step-4: In the succeeding dialog - Select ";" as the Delimiter. Look at the preview and if its ok Click "Next"

Step-5: Now you have all the attributes in separate columns.

Step-6: Build a table with attribute against the numbers

Step-7: Run vlookup on your data.

Comment: This is perfect for me. I can do this first and then create the VLOOKUP formula, and then drag it into all of the cells I need to. Brilliant thank you. And thanks you to everyone who took the time to answer :-)

Comment: @Prasanna - this is one of those features I never needed to use and forgot existed.  We could have used your input on this one: http://superuser.com/questions/822785/hiding-all-but-the-selected-rows-of-data/823367#823367

Comment: @fixer1234. Probably "Yes". But that looked like a serious solution. I haven't read it completely yet. But yes, this feature is time saving in Excel